# Why is my fragrant rice pudding (Gordon Ramsay recipe) dry?

Tags: rice

I was trying to follow the Gordon Ramsay's [recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cd6W60iW0AM) for rice pudding.

It's the first time I try a spiced rice pudding (i.e. something more than rice, milk and sugar) and I am quite happy with the flavors. The problem is that it gets very dry. I added about 750 ml liquid (milk and coconut milk) for about 250 ml of rice (yes, i measured it by volume). I was using short grained, risotto rice.

It seems to me that the mascarpone cheese and the egg yolks clump toghether in between the rice grains, and everything gets rather dry. I would prefer a creamier texture, while keeping the rice from going to mush. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

He uses Pudding Rice.

When using Risotto rice, if one wants it more starchy and to cook into a creamy texture, one usually needs to **stir** for like 15 minutes.

If at the end the result seems too dry, stir in a bit of milk at a time until you get the consistency you want.

Comment: Curious, what is pudding rice ?

Comment: @Max Well, good question, as one can use different types of rice to cook pudding, but it is what he says in the video and, from what it looks like, he is not using risotto.

Comment: @Max I think "pudding rice" is just a kind of generic short-medium grain rice that's sold specifically to be made into rice pudding.  I think its a UK/Europe thing.  I'm US-based, but I remember seeing something similar ("Milchreis" in German) in supermarkets in Germany when I was there and on certain British TV shows.

Answer (score 0):

The video does not show the final product texture when served, only what it looks in the dish, and from what I can see it looks firm.

You probably did nothing wrong.

The egg and mascarpone will make the pudding firmer when baked in the oven.

You could omit those 2 ingredients and not bake it.

Comment: Why would mascarpone make it firmer?

Comment: @canardgras mascarpone AND the egg.

Comment: Yes, I don't use these either, but that's because I like my rice pudding runny.  You can still use the same spices and get the result you want, even if you go for a more traditional texture.